# Python regular expression for exact string match including special symbols

Tags: python, regex

I am interested to use Python string match with special characters from a dictionary.

Dictionary looks like as follows:

```
    A: A:_tag
    c} c}_tag
    th th_tag
```

I am trying to use regular expression like this based on idea given in [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch03s15.html):

```
    def word_replace(text, dict):
        rc = re.compile( r'\b'+r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, dict))+r'\b')
        return rc.sub(lambda match: dict[match.group(0)], text)
```

However, it gives mapping like: `c_tag}` instead of `c}_tag` and `A_tag:` instead of `A:_tag` in a text file. What should be added in compile so that it can also consider special characters like `:` or `}` to search for a exact string?

I have also tried with following:

```
rc = re.compile(r"|".join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
```

and it still has problem with substrings, such as A:nas is replaced with A:_tagnas_tag instead of A:nas_tag. It is not searching whole string A:nas. Same goes for string like thB and th which are distinct strings. It should do thB_tag and th_tag seperate, however it do th_tagB for the first case.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please format the dictionary as actual python code. It's hard to understand as is, although I'm assuming it's strings on both sides.

Comment: `re.escape` should take care of that and you're already using it, so I'm guessing it's just a typo somewhere.

Can you post full code so we can see the actual output?

Comment: Do not use word boundaries, sort the `re.escape`d alternatives by length in descending order. If your values start/end with special chars, `\b` won't work.

Comment: Show a sample input, output and actual function call that reproduces the error.

Comment: part of dictionary is as follows: {'A:' : 'A:_tag', 'c}' : 'c}_tag'}..